# Integrating Node.js with PHP

Tags: php, node.js

I have an application developed in PHP. I'm completely new to node.js and would like to know how I can use node.js for status updates. I don't know node.js that well to have the whole appliction built in node.js. I would like to keep the PHP parts and just use node.js for updates and other real time features. Any tips?

Comment: Please read the section on getting answers to practical, detailed questions in [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Why not stick with PHP? I think you are thinking of web sockets which can be achieved with PHP

Answer (score 0):

The main aim of using node.js is to bypass the use of an apache server (like in the case of php) by developing your own web pages server.

You can still use node.js with your php app but this will get you into a lot of troubles.

If you want to add updates and real-time features i advice you to give it a try with websockets.

Have a look here to understand the functioning of node.js: http://www.toptal.com/nodejs/why-the-hell-would-i-use-node-js

and here for php websockets: http://socketo.me/

Good luck

Comment: Thanks Hosni, after a lot of research I finally chose to settle for websockets, And socketo.me was very helpful.